# 47 degrees SwipeListView: Need help to get back the frontview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, swipe

I'm using android swipelistview by 47 degrees and I'm trying to implement the swipe to call functionality.

After swiping right (exposing the backview) I need to call the frontivew after placing the call and returning to the activity.

Right now it shows the backview eventhough I reset it. I want to reset the fronview after placing a call.

I'm doing the following in my code.

```
    listView.setSwipeListViewListener(new BaseSwipeListViewListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStartOpen(int position, int action, boolean right) {

            if (context.currentOrderId != null) {
                                   }
               //Doing something
            }

            listView.closeOpenedItems();
            listView.closeAnimate(position);
            listView.setSwipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList(true);
        }
```

Comment: What's this ` 47 degrees` is that an angle?

Comment: https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have moved the listView.closeOpenedItems(); to onClickBackView and it works.